# Why does old value not passed to vue component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

why does old value not passed to vue component?

passed old value here

```html
<autocomplete-region-component :query="old('regionName')"></autocomplete-region-component>
```

my code from vue component

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            autocomplete="off"
            v-model="query"
            v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
            class="form-control js-region-name"
            name="regionName"
            value=""
        >
        <input
            type="hidden"
            class="form-control js-region-id"
            name="regionId"
            value="enteredRegion">
        <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
            <ul class="list-group select-region">
                <li class="list-group-item list-region" v-for="result in results" v-on:click="selectRegion(result)">
                    {{ result.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                results: [],
                query: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            autoComplete() {
                this.results = [];
                if(this.query.length > 2){
                    axios.get('/api/regions',{params: {_limit: 2, query: this.query}}).then(response => {
                        this.results = response.data;
                    });
                }
            },
            selectRegion(result) {
                let inputWithRegionName = document.querySelector('.js-region-name');
                let inputWithRegionId = document.querySelector('.js-region-id');
                let listRegions = document.querySelector('.panel-footer');

                inputWithRegionName.value = result.name;
                inputWithRegionId.value = result.id;
                listRegions.hidden = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

console not have mistakes

Please help with a detailed answer since I am a beginner and really need your help. thanks

---

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: because you need to define `props`? Read the Vue docs before you jump into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a prop and set the data to that prop

When you pass data in a component tag via the `v-bind` shorthand `:` these data are known as props and have to be defined as such

Vue disallows mutating props passed from the parent in the child, therefor you should make a local copy of that prop in the reactive data object

```
props: {
    queryProp: {
        required: false,
        type: String
    }
},
data() {
    return {
        results: [],
        query: this.queryProp
    };
},
```

Assuming a Blade view like so

```html
<div id="app">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="regionName"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <autocomplete-region-component :query-prop="{{ json_encode(old('regionName')) }}"></autocomplete-region-component>
</div>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

And routes like so

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Route::post('/', fn (Request $request) => $request->validate(['regionName' => 'integer']));
```

This is what you would get if invalid data is posted
[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation! but why the old value is not displayed? after submitting and form validation not completed

Answer (score 2):

When you create a component (like you have with `<autocomplete-region-component>`, if you want to pass values to it from it's parent, you have to define the prop at the component level. So in your script, add a `props` property like so:

```
    props: [
        'query',
    ],
```

Now in your autocomplete-region-component component, you can use the value of query as `this.query` as you would expect.

In your component tag, you don't use mustache tags to pass the value, you would just pass normal javascript. I'd also recommend not encoding the json at that point. You could always encode it within the component if you needed to.

```
<autocomplete-region-component :query="old('regionName')"> 
</autocomplete-region-component>
```

Comment: Right, you can't pass in a prop with the same name as a data property. Rename your local data property, or the prop.

Comment: can an example please look like it should, otherwise you can’t understand the syntax. I update vue code in main post

Answer (score 1):

Mustache syntax is to interpolate text, not to pass props.

To pass props or set attributes to child components (including native HTML elements), you need to use `v-bind` directive ([doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)).

`<a>` element is good to remember this rule.

```html
<a :href="myUrl">{{ linkText }}</a>
```

Then, your code should look like this:

```html
<autocomplete-region-component :query="json_encode(old('regionName'))"> 
</autocomplete-region-component>
```

Comment: As @Flame pointed out, you also have to define `props` option of the component which receive the props ([doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)).